# How to correct weird geometry after boolean?

Tags: modifiers, add-on, tools

I have created a mesh with boolean operations (bool tool) and I need to have it ready for 3d print. Now I've noticed some weird geometry happening but I cannot determine what it is. You can see in the screenshots that there are weird shadows in object mode but in edit mode it seems fine. I checked the normals...they appear to be on the outside. I tried remeshing and decimating but the result wasn't nice at all and I admit I probably don't master these tools very well. I attached the blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aM1ARiO9IxTEzepZK_39p1A9eDSwnGbD/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion to be able to have this ready for print.

Thank you!

[in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqd85.jpg)

[image: in object mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's one face (white outline) that is overlapping 2 edges (in red). delete that face and fill it in with 3 new faces (in green outline). the third face though will become an N-gon. better if you split it up into more faces.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Harry McKenzie!

Comment: you're welcome, glad i was able to help :)